# make a sub list of number's ranges

Tags: java

I have a list of Integers:

```
 List<Integer> integers= new ArrayList<Integer>();
 integers.add(1);
 integers.add(2);
 integers.add(3);
 integers.add(7);
 integers.add(8);
```

I want to make a list that include range of numbers like this:

- index1 = [1,3]
- index2 = [7,8]

Comment: Why do you want two separate list?? Can you explain what are you trying to solve?

Comment: it is a dynamic list, values are just samples, I wanna create sublists which contains start and end of each sequential parts. as an example I want to summarize my Grid in UI by removing duplicated rows @VaibhavRaj

Answer (score 1):

Try [subList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)

```
integers.subList(1, 3);
```

get only by the index values from 1 to 3 not by the value.

or

Your expected valueSubList

```
private static List<Integer> valueSubList(List<Integer> integers, int start, int end)
    {
        List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if (end > start)
        {
            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
            {
                if(integers.contains(i))
                {
                    subList.add(i);
                }
            }
        }

        return subList;
    }
```

Comment: Post the expected output

Comment: I need a function to create a list of all continuous numbers. Numbers are just examples. Imagine I have a big list of many numbers and I need to show just continuous pair of them.
like : (1,200)(250,300)
it helps me to summaries my list 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> index1=ArrayList<Integer>();
    index1.add(1);
    index1.add(2);
    index1.add(3);
List<Integer> index2=ArrayList<Integer>();
    index2.add(7);
    index2.add(8);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
integers.add(1);
integers.add(2);
integers.add(3);
integers.add(7);
integers.add(8);

List<List<Integer>> arrayList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(); 

arrayList.add(integers.subList(0, 3));
arrayList.add(integers.subList(3, 5));
```

Comment: I need a function to create a list of all continuous numbers. Numbers are just examples. Imagine I have a big list of many numbers and I need to show just continuous pair of them.
like : (1,200)(250,300)
it helps me to summaries my list 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given a list

```
List<Integer> integers= new ArrayList<Integer>();
integers.add(1);
integers.add(2);
integers.add(3);
integers.add(7);
integers.add(8);
```

If the list is not sorted. Sort it

```
Collections.sort(integers);
```

Now suppose you want split the list after the element with value 3

```
int key = 3;
int index = Collections.binarySearch(integers, key);
List<Integer> index1 = integers.subList(0 , index);
List<Integer> index2 = integers.subList(index+1, integers.size() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are trying to do or need something similar to partition operation of quick sort. Please check this wiki page of [quick sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). Request you to clarify your question with input/expected output.